# Mapnik render Error : Could not create datasource for type 'postgis'

Tags: postgis, mapnik, rendering

I try to use mapnik render for a tile server. During the initialization 'renderd -f -c /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf', the following error message is displayed :

```
An error occurred while loading the map layer 'xxx': Could not create 
datasource for type: 'postgis'  encountered during parsing of layer
'line features' in Layer at line 19 of 'XXX/test.xml'
```

There is no "No plugin found for type ' postgis '" displayed.

The file XXX/test.xml is the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Map [
<!ENTITY % entities SYSTEM "inc/entities.xml.inc">
 %entities;
 ]>

<Map bgcolor="#B5D2CE" srs="+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs +over">
<Style name="all_roads">
 <Rule>
  <LineSymbolizer>
   <CssParameter name="stroke">#800080</CssParameter>
   <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1.4</CssParameter>
  </LineSymbolizer>
 </Rule>
</Style>

<Layer name="line features" status="on" srs="+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs +over">
 <StyleName>all_roads</StyleName>
  <Datasource>
   <Parameter name="type">postgis</Parameter>
   <Parameter name="password">XXX</Parameter>
   <Parameter name="host">localhost</Parameter>
   <Parameter name="port">5432</Parameter>
   <Parameter name="user">XXX</Parameter>
   <Parameter name="dbname">XXX</Parameter>
   <Parameter name="table">(select way from planet_osm_line where highway is not null) as roads</Parameter>
   <Parameter name="estimate_extent">false</Parameter>
   <Parameter name="extent">-20037508,-19929239,20037508,19929239</Parameter>
 </Datasource>
</Layer>
</Map>
```

Can you help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an earlier version of Mapnik, then I think you should update the Mapnik version to 2.x and build again from source.