# Renderer error Could not create datasource for type 'postgis'

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, mapnik, rendering, postgis-2.3

I am trying to setup osm on centos 7. I have been following this link http://qiita.com/nkmrtkhd/items/642ae1b8a996cc46d85c. Most of the steps work here but I needed to do some extra googling for styling etc. So I have got the latest mapnik cause I am using the git git clone https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik. My issue is similar to this question [Mapnik render Error : Could not create datasource for type 'postgis'](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84321/mapnik-render-error-could-not-create-datasource-for-type-postgis).

When I run this renderd -f -c /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf

Below are my errors.

```
 An error occurred while loading the map layer 'default': Could not create datasource for type: 'postgis' (searched for datasource plugins in '/usr/local/lib/mapnik/input')  encountered during parsing of layer 'landuse_gen0' in Layer at line 262 of '/usr/local/share/maps/style/OSMBright/OSMBright.xml'
```

I have tried dropping the database and rebuild also nothing happens.

Here is my renderd.conf details.

```
[renderd]
socketname=/var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
plugins_dir=/usr/local/lib/mapnik/input
font_dir=/usr/share/fonts/ 
XML=/usr/local/share/maps/style/OSMBright/OSMBright.xml
HOST=localhost

[mapnik]
socketname=/var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
plugins_dir=/usr/local/lib/mapnik/input
font_dir=/usr/share/fonts/ 
XML=/usr/local/share/maps/style/OSMBright/OSMBright.xml
HOST=localhost
;plugins_dir=/usr/lib/mapnik/input
;font_dir=/usr/share/fonts/truetype
font_dir_recurse=1

[default]
socketname=/var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
plugins_dir=/usr/local/lib/mapnik/input
font_dir=/usr/share/fonts/ 
XML=/usr/local/share/maps/style/OSMBright/OSMBright.xml
HOST=localhost
```

Here is the issue which its pointing to the OSMBright.xml

```
<Layer name="landuse_gen0"
  status="on"
  srs="+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0.0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs +over">
    <StyleName>landuse_gen0</StyleName>
    <Datasource>
       <Parameter name="dbname"><![CDATA[gis]]></Parameter>
       <Parameter name="extent"><![CDATA[-20037508.34,-20037508.34,20037508.34,20037508.34]]></Parameter>
       <Parameter name="geometry_field"><![CDATA[way]]></Parameter>
       <Parameter name="id"><![CDATA[landuse_gen0]]></Parameter>
       <Parameter name="key_field"><![CDATA[]]></Parameter>
       <Parameter name="project"><![CDATA[osm-bright-imposm]]></Parameter>
       <Parameter name="srs"><![CDATA[+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0.0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs +over]]></Parameter>
       <Parameter name="table"><![CDATA[( SELECT way, way_area AS area, COALESCE(landuse, leisure, "natural", highway, amenity, tourism) AS type
  FROM planet_osm_polygon
  WHERE way_area > 100000
  ORDER BY way_area DESC
) AS data]]></Parameter>
       <Parameter name="type"><![CDATA[postgis]]></Parameter>
    </Datasource>
  </Layer>
```